# France electrical wiring

Tags: ac

We are moving to France and will be building a studio / shop / garage separate from the house. Many of my shop tools are 110V.
Does anyone know if the 240V french AC can be split into two 120V lines referenced to a neutral common and then add an earth ground (like in the US???)

Comment: No, 240V countries don't work that way. There's 240V between Line/Hot and Neutral.

Comment: You might want to check the information plate on your tools.  Many tools today use "universal" motors that will run on AC/DC/120V/240V and just about anything in between.  Many stationary tools use motors with adjustable winding connections that can be used 120V or 240V.

Comment: Wasn’t there an identical question like this yesterday?

Comment: @brhans There is no 240 V country in Europe after 2009.

Comment: @Uwe does that make any material difference to the question or to my comment?

Comment: Don't forget the change in frequency too (if there is one). France is 50 Hz and you are.... what? Some 60 Hz equipment may overheat a bit on 110 volt AC at 50 Hz.

Comment: @brhans You wrote about 240 V countries but France never was one.

Comment: Do any of your shop tools have induction motors?  (My table saw and drill press do.) 60 Hz induction motors will run at about 5/6 their rated speed on a 50 Hz supply even if you transform the voltage.  BTW, the voltage standard in France is 230V, not 240V.  In the US we use the two designations semi-interchangeably on motors for historical reasons (even motors designed for 4160V service are still rated 4000V).

Comment: @Uwe I responded to the OP's question about 240V - I never mentioned France. But even if I had, what difference would it make? The OP's 110V power tools wouldn't work any better on 230V than they would on 240V.

Comment: Andrew, what's the total power requirement for your tools. You should tally them up because it really does matter about options. Some products are only readily available in a certain range, for example. (Here, I'm thinking about double-conversion UPS, for example.)

Comment: In the UK and probably also in Europe, 110V tools are common in the construction industry. As a consequence, 230-110V transformers rated for about 3kW are common, fairly cheap, encased in tough yellow boxes from just about any builders tool store. They come with the appropriate connectors; just plug them in and go.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple tools you might consider adding a 110 V system in your shop. It's simply a 1:2 turn ratio transformer. An electrician will be able to connect it at least if you get the transformer and tell them to bring all the rest. I say electrician, because you are not allowed to do "semi-permanent" installations and the electrician will know the local regulations on socket types etc.

Free running voltage of the transformer will be higher than specified, depending on the selected transformer, so your switches, relays, contactors need to withstand the higher voltage. If you have more sophisticated devices than motors you need a regulator device or dummy load like a heater, which adds to cost.

I would pick the previously described way, as it is the safe and simple solution. You have probably noticed devices sold by the name "230 to 110 converter", but they most likely will not work with inductive load from workshop machinery and might present a fire hazard if used out of the specified conditions.

Comment: *do not* use one of those cheap converter boxes for anything other than a resistive load (incandescent lighting, heaters)! It will not end well for the converter box or the expensive tool you plugged into it!

Comment: So does that mean that if I use an auto transformer across the 240 to output two 120v lines, the winding will need to be 60mH with a CT to yield two 20A circuits?

Comment: I would not use the converter boxes for high currents or non-resistive loads either, just out of fear of fire, but I have no evidence on risks. It's really up to the converter box and some of them might be high quality, I do not know.

Comment: I edited the text to make it clearer that converter boxes might be a safety issue.

Comment: @Andrew do not expect 240 V in France, it is 230 V.

Comment: @Andrew, what do you mean by 60 mH (a measure of inductance)? Is it a typo? An isolating transformer would be better than an autotransformer as the secondary centre-tap could be grounded.

Comment: I think I screwed up my calc. Should be an autotransformer 14.64H with a CT to yield 2 20A/115V circuits from one 230V single phase circuit.

Comment: That makes sense. The alternative provides a separate earth ground.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked my cordless electric screwdriver, it will work with any voltage between 100 and 240 V and with 50 Hz as well as 60 Hz. No need to change a jumper.

There are many electric equipment designed to be sold all over the world to work with 100 to 120 V and 220 to 240 V as well as 50 and 60 Hz.

So check all tools and other equipment which is specified for 120 V only or 60 Hz only. If those are a small and cheap minority, there might be a cheap and easy solution to replace only them by tools sold in France.

Comment: a cordless electric screwdriver works on DC

Comment: @jsotola The charger for the screwdriver is pluged to AC and charges DC.